# How has my php file's encoding changed when editing with vim?

Tags: php, vim, encoding, utf-8

I have been editing php files using vim over SSH with PuTTY with encoding=utf-8, fileencodings=utf-8. Unicode is needed because I have simplified Chinese characters that need to be echoed. Everything has been fine since the web site's start (the response headers are set...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

...the html specifies unicode in a meta tag, etc.).

However, today I start vim, and all the Chinese characters are shown as rectangles. I reconfirmed the encoding settings, but still no luck.

The pages are still being served *correctly* (unicode with Chinese characters), so I think the files are indeed still encoded the same.

Any suggestions to get vim to read/write the encodings correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PuTTY translation was set correctly to UTF-8. My solution ended up being to change the window font (under Appearance) from Courier to a simplified Chinese font (SimSun, or KaiTi, or something similar).

To be clear, Courier was working a week ago. My guess is that Windows falls back on some default Chinese font for displaying those characters. Perhaps that fallback got broken between Windows and PuTTY? Anyways, Chinese font for Chinese characters = solved.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have configured PuTTy's encoding properly ? By default, it doesn't use UTF-8.

Right-click on the title's bar, go to something like Window > Translation *(I don't have putty on my current computer, so not sure -- but should look like this)*.

There, you'll find a dropdown with several encoding -- including UTF-8 ; make sure it's the selected one.